# pass an anaconda boot option to a kickstart file in rhel7 initial install

Tags: redhat, rhel7, kickstart, anaconda

Is there a way to pass an anaconda boot option to a kickstart file, where it could be used as a variable.

Say anaconda boot cmd is
xxxx ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask=255.255.255.0 gateway=xxx.xxx.xxx.1
ksdevice=b ks=

I wanted to know if there was a way to access the "ip" value within ks script

Comment: You should be able to parse the value from `/proc/cmdline`.

Comment: For some reason there are none of the network values in /proc/cmdline